# Android: How can I display a list of categorised video thumbnails that expand on click?

Tags: android, gridview, expandablelistview

First I'll show you what I have in mind.

```
CATEGORY 1
Video 1 | Video 2 | Video 3
Video 4 | Video 5 | Video 6

CATEGORY 2
Video 1 | Video 2 | Video 3
Video 4 | Video 5 | Video 6
```

In reality there are more categories, but to keep it short, I limited it to two. Now let's say a user is interested in more videos from CATEGORY 1 and let's presume there are ten video's in this category. I would want the view to be like this:

```
CATEGORY 1
Video 1 | Video 2 | Video 3
Video 4 | Video 5 | Video 6
Video 7 | Video 8 | Video 9
Video 10

CATEGORY 2
Video 1 | Video 2 | Video 3
Video 4 | Video 5 | Video 6
```

So in this case, still both categories and their videos would be visible, but for category one the list would be totally expanded. If a user would click on CATEGORY 1 again, the result would be the same list as the one on the top.

Currently a GridView is being used to show all the video's, without the separation in categories and the possibility to expand categories. Since GridView does not support sections, it is not suitable for the new approach though.

I was think about using a ScrollView with GridViews inside it for every category, but if I expand one of the GridViews, an OutOfMemoryException occurs, because all of the category's images are loaded at once. Besides that, this feels kinda hacky and I would think that there are better solutions to solve this.

An alternative I looked at is an ExpandableListView. What I do not know though, is if it's possible to to add a section to it that contains some already visible items and show the rest of the items once it's clicked on.

Do you guys think this is a good alternative or are there other options that I should contemplate looking at? Thanks already for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use RecyclerView, which manage memory itself.

add dependency to gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

then, [here is basic of RecyclerView](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/)

ok, now assume that you know how to use RecyclerView.

we two level datas define:

- first level model is a category with a list,
- second level model is Movie.

so two level views define:

- first level view is a RecyclerView contains many RecyclerView(depends on your count of categories)
- second level view is a RecyclerView contains many Movie.

[here is code on github](https://github.com/grantonzhuang/Q35815072)

key code in FirstAdapter:

```
// click show only 6, click again show all
public void showOrCollapse() {
    if (showAll && secondModel2Show.size() >= 6) {
        this.secondModel2Show = this.secondModel2Show.subList(0, 6);
    } else {
        this.secondModel2Show = this.secondModels;
    }
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    showAll = !showAll;
}
```

ket code in SecondAdapter

```
// bind data to view
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FirstHolder holder, int position) {
    FirstModel firstModel = firstModels.get(position);
    holder.cat.setText(firstModel.getCat());
    final SecondAdapter secondAdapter = new SecondAdapter(firstModel.getSecondModels());
    holder.rcv.setLayoutManager(new FullyGridLayoutManager(activity, 3));
    holder.rcv.setAdapter(secondAdapter);
    holder.cat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            secondAdapter.showOrCollapse();
        }
    });
}
```

first model

```
public class FirstModel {

    private String cat;

    private List<SecondModel> secondModels;

}
```

second model

```
public class SecondModel {

    private int res;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot into the right direction!